# How to convert numbers back to string in Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm new to elixir and I'm excited. I did play around with Binary like below in IEX terminal.

```
iex(34)> world = <<119,111,114,108,100>>
"world"

iex(35)> <<x::size(40)>> = world
"world"

iex(36)> x
512970878052
```

I really don't know what number **512970878052** represents, but I really want to convert it back to a word **"world"**. How can I do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the exact same expression to convert back!

```
iex(1)> world = <<119,111,114,108,100>>
"world"
iex(2)> <<x::size(40)>> = world
"world"
iex(3)> x
512970878052
iex(4)> <<x::size(40)>>
"world"
```

(You can also write just `<<x::40>>` instead of `<<x::size(40)>>` in both cases.)

---

> I really don't know what number 512970878052 represents

That's the integer represented by the bytes `[119, 111, 114, 108, 100]` when interpreted as an unsigned big-endian integer, i.e.

```
iex(5)> use Bitwise
Bitwise
iex(6)> 119 <<< 32 ||| 111 <<< 24 ||| 114 <<< 16 ||| 108 <<< 8 ||| 100
512970878052
```

Comment: I can get 119 from 512970878052 by: 512970878052 >>> 32 ... but I couldn't get 111 and so on... I'm sorry I really never done any bit operations :P. It's first time I required to build binary messaging over tcp for game

Comment: You need to remove everything after the least significant byte. Try `512970878052 >>> n &&& 0xff` where `n` is `32`, `24`, and so on.

Comment: @BromoProgrammer to get 119, 111 etc one might `<<x1::8, x2::8, x3::8, x4::8, x5::8, _ :: binary>> = <<512970878052::40>>`. Since you seem to require lot of these transforms, I would go with writing a macro like `get_byte(position, input)`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I'm still learning elixir from ebook, haven't reach to creating macro yet ... I wiil (excited) ... thanks ;)

Comment: @mudasobwa or just use `:binary.at/2` to pluck a single byte: `:binary.at("foo", 1) #=> 111`.

Comment: @Dogbert I did not mean to reinvent `:binary.at/2` functionality, I meant to extract the portions with pattern match, like `<<_::8, flag::24, _::binary>>`.

Comment: That was for your suggestion of a macro `get_byte(position, input)`. That's equivalent to `:binary.at` right?